# How to Remove specific field from List of models

Tags: c#, list, linq, generic-list

Class structure

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
   {
       public List<EmployeeDetails > employeedetails { get; set; }
       public string age { get; set; }
   }
public class EmployeeDetails 
   {
       public string empid { get; set; }
       public string empname { get; set; }
   }
```

List of employee details

```
empid  empname  age
-----  ------- -----
1      Faizy   2 years
2      Jaan    5 years
3      Ajith   8 years
```

I want to remove one field from list object like empid, like below output

```
empname  age
------- -----
Faizy   2 years
Jaan    5 years
Ajith   8 years
```

Comment: you want to modiy your class or suppress it in your output? xy-problem?

Comment: Your EmployeeViewModel structure looks odd. Not sure why you would have a single age (also as a string not an int) alongside a list of employee details.

Comment: Okay... and how is its output generated?

Comment: Makes more sense to have `age` in `EmployeeDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ will never change your sources. It can only extract data from the sources. If desired, you can use the extracted data to change your sources.

So you have one EmployeeViewModels, which has a list of EmployeeDetails (which can be null!).

You want a new sequence with only empName and Age of each employeeDetail in the list of EmployeeDetails. If the viewModel has a null EmployeeDetails, you want an empty list.

```
EmployeeViewModel viewModel = ...
IEnumerable<EmployeeDetail> employeeDetails = viewModel.EmployeeDetails ??
    Enumerable.Empty<EmployeeDetail>();
var result = employeeDetails.Select(employeeDetail => new
{
     Name = employeeDetail.EmpName,
     Age = employeeDetail.EmpAge,
});
```